# How to ground STP cable?

Tags: cabling, layer1

I just happened to buy a lot of CAT6a STP cable and shielded CAT6a RJ45 keystone modules for wall outlets. I understand it was completely unnecessary to buy this kind of stuff, but it is too late...

I have an 1 Gbps modem (actually combined modem and router) and 1Gbps integrated ethernet in the motherboards of the PCs and who knows what in the smart TVs. The modem plug does not have grounding. How can I ground the shielding of the STP cable? Is it necessary to ground it?

Comment: For the shielding to work correctly, the equipment must be compliant with shielded cable so that it properly grounds it. Most enterprise-grade equipment does this.

Comment: @RonMaupin This one is coming from the ISP, so I guess it is something cheap. This is just a home network, not an enterprise one.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networks are explicitly off-topic here. Also, unless you have the proper equipment (very expensive testers, etc.) and a lot of experience with cable installation, you are not going to be able to get the cabling to pass the test suite. Even experienced installers have problems with Category-6 and above cable installation.

Comment: I agree with Gadeliow; improper grounding, degraded grounding (i.e., neglected over time), or missing shield ground will cause far more problems that it ever solved, especially in a home environment. If you decide to proceed with using shielded cabling, make sure all your other components are of the proper matched type or you will have wasted a great deal of time and money to install an unrated (i.e., Cat-Nothing) system. Isolated grounding is not necessary; facilities ground is preferred, but it has to be tested and good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sure ,there is no necessary to ground it ,it can work just like normal UTP ,by the way There are a number of reasons you don't use shielded cable in the home environments  ,Technically it should be grounded at one point (the patch panel) using a copper bus bar that attaches to vertically buried 6 foot long copper rod via at least a 6 gauge cable, isolated from the electrical system ground.

> Don't use the ground pins in the outlets. You will likely cause a
>   grounding  loop which will give you more noise (and possibly a 'ground
>   short' which can cause a fire) than running unshielded cable.

Comment: Can you elaborate please! Where are these grounding pins, and how not to use them?

Comment: A Google image search turned up this: https://www.air802.com/RJ45-modular-shielded-plug-cat5e-round-cable-solid-stranded.html -- if your plugs don't look like that, they don't have ground pins per se (NEVER connect the shielding to any of the 8 pins in a standard RJ45 plug!)